# How to fix Heroku error: Process exited with status 129

Tags: node.js, heroku

> 2018-05-14T09:12:46.770011+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `node musicology.js` by user leshaber24@yandex.ru
>   
> 2018-05-14T09:12:50.704836+00:00 heroku[run.5756]: Awaiting client
>   
> 2018-05-14T09:12:50.760658+00:00 heroku[run.5756]: Starting process with command `node musicology.js`
>   
> 2018-05-14T09:12:50.767575+00:00 heroku[run.5756]: State changed from starting to up
>   
> 2018-05-14T09:12:56.951346+00:00 heroku[run.5756]: Client connection closed. Sending SIGHUP to all processes
>   
> 2018-05-14T09:12:57.484760+00:00 heroku[run.5756]: Process exited with status 129
>   
> 2018-05-14T09:12:57.499531+00:00 heroku[run.5756]: State changed from up to complete

These are the logs coming from Heroku. My app is here: https://github.com/Alesha24/mysicology_telegram_bot

I've already fixed an error with SIGKILL command, now (after doing `node musicology.js`) error is of status 129 and moreover this one:

> Error R13 (Attach error) -> Failed to attach to process

This error also appears to be unclear for me. Any ideas of way, how can I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Application error after succeeded Heroku Build (Node + React App)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49674508/application-error-after-succeeded-heroku-build-node-react-app)